# Dangerous Questions tag

Tags: feature-request

I've noticed quite a few questions where I'd be very uncomfortable driving anywhere ***near*** the question asker, as they clearly have a very serious issue that affects the way their vehicle steers, brakes or is otherwise controlled

Should we implement a tag which can be applied (I'm thinking something like the "Protected" tag) that should immediately flag to any non-mechanically minded types that the defect is dangerous and to seek qualified assistance?

Comment: note - I'm thinking both for the wellbeing of the question answerer and anyone who comes across it here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't disagree with the intent of your idea but I tend to say what you're suggesting right in the **tl;dr** at the top of the post.

A tag is a different featured, focused on filtering and searching.  I'd prefer not to have people searching our site for dangerous ideas (but that's just me... ;-).

Comment: Agree. I think if an answerer needs to specify to the OP the danger. That can be done with bold and/or large text. A tag is the wrong way to go here.